# css absolute position not moving image

Tags: css

I have a div containing just the image inside a div containg all the text (writing a tutorial).

the html is

```
<div class="hav">
<img src="presentation/hav.png" alt="hav.png" title"hav" />
</div>
```

the css on the style sheet is

```
#hav
{
position: absolute;
top: 600px;
left: 200px;
}
```

any guesses? I know this is simple. It just won't move.

Answer (score 6):

You have the div with a class of "hav", but you're referencing an ID of "hav" in your CSS. Change **#hav** to **.hav**

Comment: Thank you. I meant to have an ID.

Comment: Top tip, avoid ID usage since you can only ever have one of the same id on a page. Also your "title" attribute is missing a "=" :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the CSS to be `.hav`. The `#` in CSS refers to an id, `.` refers to a class which you specified on the `div`.

Comment: Thank you. I need the positioning for a unique element. I meant to have an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
position:fixed;
```

like in [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed).